# How do I fill a child entity with data from DB from inside an aggregate root?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, solid-principles

I have an aggregate root `Entity` which does some processing when requested. If during that processing a condition is met, then `SubEntity` has to be initialized. The problem is that `SubEntity` has also a child entity `Status` which has to be initialized with a starting value that comes from the DB.

I'm trying to closely follow SOLID and DDD principles, but I'm new at this. The way I have it working now is by using a factory, but it looks wrong to me, because I don't like the idea of having this factory being served by a consumer class (in order to follow [DIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)), since this is part of the domain logic within that entity.

Am I doing this right? Is this the correct way to design such classes? What alternatives do I have?

```c#
public class Entity
{
    public virtual SubEntity SubEntity { get; private set; }

    public void Process(int someData, ISubEntityFactory subEntityFactory)
    {
        if (SomeConditionIsMet)
        {
            SubEntity = subEntityFactory.Create(this);
        }
    }
}

public class SubEntity
{
    public SubEntity(Entity entity, Status status)
    {
        Entity = entity;
        Status = status;
    }

    public virtual Entity Entity { get; private set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; private set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public const int StartingId = 1;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubEntity> SubEntity { get; private set; }
}

public class SubEntityFactory : ISubEntityFactory
{
    // property and constructor omitted
    public SubEntity Create(Entity entity)
    {
        var status = UnitOfWork.StatusRepository.GetByID(Status.StartingId);

        return new SubEntity(entity, status);
    }
}
```

---

### Solution

Based on theDmi's great answer, I decided to receive a `initialStatus` variable as a parameter to the `Process` method, so my domain is not coupled to the DB. Then I validate `initialStatus` to make sure its `id` matches `Status.StartingId`. After that, I don't even need the factory anymore, and it looks a lot cleaner.

```c#
public class Entity
{
    public virtual SubEntity SubEntity { get; private set; }

    public void Process(int someData, Status initialStatus)
    {
        ValidateInitialStatus(initialStatus);

        if (SomeConditionIsMet)
        {
            SubEntity = new SubEntity(this, initialStatus);
        }
    }

    private void ValidateInitialStatus(Status initialStatus)
    {
        if (initialStatus == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("initialStatus");
        }

        if (initialStatus.Id != Status.StartingId)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Initial status is invalid");
        }
    }
}

public class SubEntity
{
    public SubEntity(Entity entity, Status status)
    {
        Entity = entity;
        Status = status;
    }

    public virtual Entity Entity { get; private set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; private set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public const int StartingId = 1;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubEntity> SubEntity { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: I would like to talk about just a little logic here. When using something passed in from outside, you use services (data and method) of it. So without using it, you surely need to somehow put all the necessary code and logic in the `Entity` class instead. That's all. When it comes to creating new `SubEntity` it also depends on how you can do to create it (you use some factory so looks like there are different ways of creating it). From your code, you use just the `new` operator (maybe it is just some example code?).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Indeed, I'm not happy with the way this factory is written, because I only need one result out of it, it's not supposed to provide anything other than `Status` of id=1. And I also don't like that it's being handed to the method, since that knowledge should be contained within the `Entity` domain entity. No one should be able to provide a different behavior to the `Process` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `UnitOfWork.StatusRepository.GetByID(Status.StartingId)` in your factory seems fishy. Try to avoid coupling factories to repositories (though the other way around is ok, e.g. to use a factory during reconstitution).

A clean solution would be the following:

```
public class Entity
{
    private readonly ISubEntityFactory _subEntityFactory; 

    public Entity(ISubEntityFactory subEntityFactory) {
        _subEntityFactory = subEntityFactory;
    }

    public void Process(int someData, Status initialStatus)
    {
        if (SomeConditionIsMet)
        {
            SubEntity = _subEntityFactory.Create(this, initialStatus);
        }
    }
}
```

This has the consequence that the `initialStatus` must be retrieved by the calling app service. I guess you wanted to avoid that, **but it is a lot cleaner than coupling the domain to the DB** (which I'd avoid at all cost).

If you can, redesign the `initialStatus` as value object. I don't know if that's possible in your case, but it would make the design more robust.

Also, don't pass `subEntityFactory` as parameter. A factory is a special kind of a service, so it should be injected into constructors rather than passed around. This makes the dependency of `Entity` on the factory explicit, which is good.

Note that having service dependencies in entities usually leads to the conclusion that it's best to create or reconstitute the entity through a factory. That way, the factory can provide all services required by the specific entity when constructing it. Always remember that **object construction is an implementation detail**, clients don't need to know about it in order to use an object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm using Entity Framework, which [requires entities to have a parameterless constructor](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3820.entity-framework-faq-entity-classes.aspx#Does_the_Entity_Framework_require_objects_with_public_empty_constructors), so I can't pass it on the constructor. I only tagged the question with "ef", but I didn't make it clear on the question, sorry. I totally agree about not coupling the domain to the DB. I think I can't use Value Objects or Enum because the `Status` entity has properties that may change (e.g. `Description`).

Comment: I also agree that this factory is odd. Following your example, perhaps I don't even need the factory then, I could validate the `Status` entity received in the Process method with: `if (initialStatus.Id != Status.StartingId) throw;`, and then just `SubEntity = new SubEntity(this, initialStatus);`. What do you think?

Comment: I also used EF with DDD in the last project, trying to use your domain model with EF directly is going to compromise the expressiveness of your model. You already see this happening by being forced to have constructors without parameters. I strongly suggest you introduce a mapping from domain to db entities and use EF only on the db entities. Everything else is not going to be very DDDish I'm afraid.